# How to find the size of a column in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, command-line-interface, hector

I am running into Java heap size issues, so wanted to check what is the size of a column in cassandra. I am reading many columns into Java in memory.

Thanks for the help this

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any built-in way to do this without retrieving the column and checking the size directly.

You would need to store the size of each column in *another* column, when the value is originally written.

You could use a similarly-named column in the same row, so you end up with the same number of rows as you have now, but twice as many columns in each)

```
row :  col1    col1size    col2    col2size
       <data>  <size>      <data>  <size>
```

or an identically-named column in another row, so you end up with twice as many rows, but the same number of columns as you have now).

```
row1       :  col1    col2
              <data>  <data>

row1sizes  :  col1    col2  
              <size>  <size>
```

**Updated** to address comment: To find the size of the column before writing it, the client could serialize the object to a byte array and then check the size of the array:

```
    String s = "foo";
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
    oos.writeObject(s);
    System.out.println("Size="+baos.toByteArray().length);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But my column value is a java serialized object. How do I get the size of it?